# How set name for crawled table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

AWS crawler has prefix property for adding new tables. So If I leave prefix empty and start crawler to `s3://my-bucket/some-table-backup` it creates table with name `some-table-backup`. Is there a way to rename it to `my-awesome-table` and keep crawler updating renamed table? Or set up crawler to create new table with provided name?

Answer (score 8):

It's not possible to set up the crawler to do this, but it is very fast to create a new table that is the same as the table created by the crawler in every way, except the name.  In [Python](https://gist.github.com/dan-hook/843ac18047906e506f447becc4231a61):

```py
import boto3

database_name = "database"
table_name = "prefix-dir_name"
new_table_name = "more_awesome_name"
    
client = boto3.client("glue")
response = client.get_table(DatabaseName=database_name, Name=table_name)
table_input = response["Table"]
table_input["Name"] = new_table_name

# Delete keys that cause create_table to fail
table_input.pop("CreatedBy")
table_input.pop("CreateTime")
table_input.pop("UpdateTime")
table_input.pop("DatabaseName")
table_input.pop("IsRegisteredWithLakeFormation")
catalog_id = table_input.pop("CatalogId")
client.create_table(
 DatabaseName=database_name, 
 TableInput=table_input, 
 CatalogId=catalog_id
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Encountered the same issue. Needed to drop more attributes than in Dan Hook's answer before the table could be queried in Redshift.

```
table_input="$(aws glue --region us-west-2 get-table --database-name database --name old_table --query 'Table' | jq '{Name: "new_table", StorageDescriptor, TableType, Parameters}')"

aws glue create-table --region us-west-2 --database-name database --table-input "$table_input"
aws glue delete-table --region us-west-2 --database-name database --name "old_table"
```

Comment: good approach, but this didn't work with partitioned table.

Answer (score 2):

Extension to Dan's solution but with partitioned table.

```
import boto3

database_name = "some_database"
table_name = "old_table_name"
new_table_name = "new_table_name"

client = boto3.client("glue", region_name='us-east-1')
response = client.get_table(DatabaseName=database_name, Name=table_name)
partitions = client.get_partitions(DatabaseName=database_name, TableName=table_name)["Partitions"]
table_input = response["Table"]
table_input["Name"] = new_table_name

# Delete keys that cause create_table to fail
table_input.pop("CreatedBy")
table_input.pop("CreateTime")
table_input.pop("UpdateTime")
table_input.pop("DatabaseName")
table_input.pop("IsRegisteredWithLakeFormation")

# Delete unnecessary keys in partitions
for partition in partitions:
    partition.pop("DatabaseName")
    partition.pop("TableName")
    partition.pop("CreationTime")

# Create new table table
client.create_table(DatabaseName=database_name, TableInput=table_input)

# Create partitions
client.batch_create_partition(DatabaseName=database_name, TableName=new_table_name, PartitionInputList=partitions)
```

Answer (score 0):

As dan mentioned, Crawlers can't rename the table. Either rename using a python script in the glue job or create an new external hive table in amazon-athena and point it to the location of the old table.

Answer (score 0):

To further extend on Dan's answer, please make sure you remove `VersionId` as well. See below for an update:

```
import boto3

database_name = "database"
table_name = "prefix-dir_name"
new_table_name = "more_awesome_name"
    
client = boto3.client("glue")
response = client.get_table(DatabaseName=database_name, Name=table_name)
table_input = response["Table"]
table_input["Name"] = new_table_name

# Delete keys that cause create_table to fail
table_input.pop("CreatedBy")
table_input.pop("CreateTime")
table_input.pop("UpdateTime")
table_input.pop("DatabaseName")
table_input.pop("IsRegisteredWithLakeFormation")
table_input.pop("VersionId")
catalog_id = table_input.pop("CatalogId")
client.create_table(
 DatabaseName=database_name, 
 TableInput=table_input, 
 CatalogId=catalog_id
)
```